# how to extrude a curve to create a hollow torus

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]i created a mesh torus to scale.

however, the design has multiple tori.

i am concerned about the weight. with the specs based on a solid torus, the end result would be very heavy.

is there a way to make a hollow torus and specify the thickness?

i saw a similar post about extruding along a circular path to create a torus, but it seems like the suggestions would still result in a solid object.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about Bevel for Curve:

- Create two curves, one for section (tori), one for path;
- Select the path curve, find **Bevel Object** in its Object Data panel, choose the other one as the bevel object. Then you can scale either of them to change both ratios for it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am not sure if i am missing something, but wouldn't this still create a solid object as an end result? the bevel is being applied to only one measurement, the tori. there would need to be two measurements to specify either thickness or an inner and outer diameter.

Comment: @user2471 See my updated GIF. Actually, you can change both diameter dynamically. It's just an example. I suggest to do it in Edit mode though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [*Solidify*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Solidify) modifier to make an object hollow:

[image]

The above screenshot is taken with a [*Clipping border*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View#View_Clipping_Border) in effect to show that the torus is hollow.

Also note that unless you need the ends of a curve to be filled or use, there is no need to use a bevel object. Since a torus does not have ends, using a bevel object is not necessary unless you want a non-circular profile.

There is nothing wrong with using a bevel object, as a matter of fact it gives you more control. I thought I'd point this out because it does not seem to be necessary in your case.

To make a torus from a curve circle object without using a bevel object:

1. Set the *Fill* in *Curve > Shape* to *Full*
2. Set the *Depth* in *Curve > Geometry > Bevel* to the overall thickness of the curve.
3. Set the *Resolution* in *Curve > Geometry > Bevel* to the the number of minor subdivisions you want.

   [image]

If you then add the solidify modifier, you will have a hollow torus like in the first screenshot.

- You can adjust the thickness with the *Thickness* setting the the *Solidify modifier*.
- You can adjust the minor radius with the *Bevel depth*, or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> in edit mode.
- You can adjust the major radius by scaling the curve (<kbd>S</kbd>)

For example:

[image]

Comment: @user2471 Ah, I didn't follow your meaning by "thickness". Please consider to accept this as your answer, if it works to you. :)